# Check elapsed time for mysql queries

Tags: query, mysql-5.7

I'm not much familier with mysql. We hit a strange scenario. There were lot of 'select' queries hitting database at the same time.All were same 'select' with some different parameters value and they were using indexes. Since, those all were select - I didn't see any blocker.
When, all queries were hitting the database the average query execution time starts becoming slow. The query which usually takes 1 sec for execution was taking 10 -12 seconds for execution at that time. When, I run query manually - it was taking the same execution time (1 sec) which it usually take.

I checked at that time -> there was no max number of connection reached/no high io problem.
I thought it was elapsed time may be. But, is there any way in mysql to check query elapsed time? or any waiting queue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may wish to use the built in Slow Query Log as documented in this URL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html - for your purpose, long_query_time of 2 (seconds) would be appropriate in your my.cnf or my.ini.

Comment: we use slow query log- but the thing is that - it doesn't clarify if it's actual execution time for elapsed time for the query.

Comment: Please post last 100 lines of your slow query log and I will show you where the execution time has been posted.

Comment: Thanks. I know where is execution time there. But, I want to know if there is any way in mysql to check elapsed time.  The execution time - I shared in question 10 -12 seconds - I picked from those slow_query logs only.

Comment: From MySQL Command Prompt, SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; has a 'TIME' column you may be looking for. If your OS is Linux, you may find the TIME column on TOP or HTOP report.

Comment: Another option that may have details you need. 
top -H -p PID   for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck - for sharing these options.  How can we sure that it's elapsed time. Also, this we can't see once query got executed

Comment: With a stop watch and familarity what you are testing and how long it takes.  To confirm with these viewing options.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - It's not testing. It's actual prod. If any query is taking time for prod without any blocking and taking more time than it usually take when we run it directly at the same time. I want to investigate why it is taking so long. To check that, other databases provide execution time and elapsed time separately(Like : Oracle). For postgres - we can see wait_queue in db logs and identify. Likewise, I didn't find any way to check in mysql. So, asking.

Comment: Please post result of SELECT @@version; . Have you considered enabling PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA for additional detailed information?  Use of PROFILING when available gets down to the nitty gritty of processing required to complete a query in great detail.